Adding Form Inputs Dynamically with Javascript and Thymeleaf
I'm wondering what is the most idiomatic/optimal solution is for adding form elements dynamically with Javascript and Thymeleaf. For context, I have a form that is being generated server side like so:
<form
    th:action="@{/some/path})}"
    th:object="${pathBulletinForm}"
    method="post"
    class="mb-3 border rounded needs-validation"
    novalidate
    id="bulletinForm"
>
    <select th:field="*{conditionRating}" type="select" id="conditionRating" name="conditionRating" class="form-select">
        <option label="-- Select a Condition --" value=""></option>
        <option th:each="pathConditionOpt : ${T(com.francisbailey.pathbulletin.persistence.model.PathCondition).values()}" th:value="${pathConditionOpt}" th:text="${pathConditionOpt.displayName}" th:attr="data-description='descriptionFor' + ${pathConditionOpt.name}"></option>
    </select>
    <a href="#" id="addConditionRating"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Add Rating</i>
</form>

Now, what I'd like to do is for the user to click a button and it will automatically append an identical select drop down to the form. In other words they can have multiple "conditionRatings" appended to the form. This is easy enough to do in pure javascript/client side, but I like having the drop down generated server side since the values are coming from an enum and single source of truth.
I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. Setting this template value in Javascript looks possible, but kind of ugly.
For adding the form element I know I can do something like:
<script>
const ratingButton = document.getElementById("addConditionRating");
const form = document.getElementById("bulletinForm")

ratingButton.addEventListener(e => {
    form.appendChild(`<select>My Condition Ratings Template Here?</select>`);    
});
</script>

However, I'm not sure on how to set the actual select drop down in there. I also need to bind a listener to each drop down to display a server side rendered description/label underneath the drop down.

One option would be to put the dropdown code into a fragment.  Then you can use the same code in your page, and add another controller method to just return the condition dropdown.  Something like this for example:
page.html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-/JqT3SQfawRcv/BIHPThkBvs0OEvtFFmqPF/lYI/Cxo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
        $(function() {
            $('#addConditionRating').click(() => {
                $.get('/condition',(data) => {
                    $('#conditionContainer').append(data);
                }); 
            });
        });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form
        th:action="@{/some/path}"
        th:object="${pathBulletinForm}"
        method="post"
        class="mb-3 border rounded needs-validation"
        novalidate
        id="bulletinForm"
    >
        <div id="conditionContainer">
            <th:block th:replace="~{fragments :: condition}" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="addConditionRating"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle"></i> Add Rating</i>
    </form>
</body>

fragments.html
<html>
    <body>
        <select th:fragment="condition" type="select" id="conditionRating" name="conditionRating" class="form-select">
            <option label="-- Select a Condition --" value=""></option>
            <option th:each="pathConditionOpt : ${T(com.francisbailey.pathbulletin.persistence.model.PathCondition).values()}"
                    th:value="${pathConditionOpt}"
                    th:text="${pathConditionOpt.displayName}"
                    th:attr="data-description='descriptionFor' + ${pathConditionOpt.name}"></option>
        </select>
    </body>
</html>

And then add a controller method that returns that page fragment:
@GetMapping("/condition")
public String condition() {
    return "fragments :: condition";
}

